# LABVIEW matrix to graylevel picture

Tags: arrays, matrix, styles, labview

I'm using camera mightex bte-b050-u
and using the example the company gave using labview I created a 2D array and want to transform it into a grayscale photo. I have no idea how to do it since I don't know labview and using the code in matlab it has many errors.

I'd appreciate if someone could please let me know how I can take this 2D array and represent it as a grayscale photo. (beam profiler if you wish)

P.s

[image]

I have no idea why they ignored 28 "words" so I just tried going with that logic and transform it to my camera according to the pixels I have.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to read about intensity graph.
And use the linked article which would explain on how to change the color scale on the graph.

[Changing the color on an Intensity Graph](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/1ADFF221E27F5B5886256E6F007C7B58)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that converts a 2-D array into an image: [Convert Array to Image](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-4155).

In short, use `Flatten Pixmap.vi`, `Draw Flattened Pixmap.vi`, and `Picture to Pixmap.vi` from the NI-IMAQ palette, which is part of the [Vision Application Software](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-vision-acquisition-software-august-2016/6306/en/) SDK.